# Custom Wordpress menu structure

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, structure

I'm new to Wordpress and coding a custom structure for my main nav menu as I need to be able to put columns in the submenu div's. However, my code isn't working:

```
            <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
          <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">

            <?php
            $menuname = wp_get_nav_menu_object("Menu 1" );
            $menu_name = $menuname->name;
            $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
            $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
            $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );

            $count = 0;
            $submenu = false;

            foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
                    // set up title and url
              $title = $item->title;
              $link = $item->url;

              // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
              if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):
              // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
                $parent_id = $item->ID;
            ?>

                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children">
                  <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>

                  <?php

                  endif;

                  if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ):
                    if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>

                      <ul class="sub-menu">

                      <?php endif; ?>

                      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
                      </li>
                      <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ): ?>

                        </ul>

                      <?php
                      $submenu = false; endif;
                      endif;
                      ?>

              <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ): ?>
                </li>

                <?php
                $submenu = false; endif;
                $count++; endforeach;
                ?>


          </ul>
        </div>
```

Currently no menu is being displayed at all, I checked if I spelled the menu name correctly and I Did. can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to work with woker class?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a simple query for its menus.

`<?php 
      wp_nav_menu( 
       array( 
              'theme_location' => 'primary', 
              'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' 
       ) 
      ); 
 ?>`

You can read more from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/ You can easily adjust this with css and javascript. but like @akshay-shah states, you can use the nav walker class if you wish to use css frameworks like bootstrap. Ref: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker